# Can I use RDS Multiple-AZ together with Read-Replica?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

RDS **Multiple-AZ** gives me the fail-over automatically when the master is down the standby instance will be promoted as mater, OFC they are synchronized,

With a few **Read-Replica** the over-all performance will be good.

So can I have them both at the same time, as shown below, for example:

```
Master --(across AZ)-- standby 
|
Read-Replica instance1
|
Read-Replica instance2
```

In the above case, I believe if Master is down, the standby will be as master, but question is whether the Read-Replica will break or not?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what flavor of RDS you are using - If you are using RDS for MySQL, MariaDB or PostgreSQL, you can use RDS read replicas with Multi-AZ configurations.

See [Amazon RDS Read Replicas Now Support Multi-AZ Deployments](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/amazon-rds-read-replicas-now-support-multi-az-deployments/)